# Change the column type and data conversion

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a column planned_duration that stores the time in minutes and is of type integer. You need to change the type to interval and to convert existing data. For this I wrote this SQL code:

```
ALTER TABLE shift ALTER COLUMN planned_duration TYPE INTERVAL USING planned_duration * INTERVAL '60 sec';
```

But unfortunately it does not work. I get this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: interval >= integer
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What you need to do to properly change the column type and convert the data? Thanks.

Comment: `select * from shift where planned_duration > 60* INTERVAL '60 sec'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was to in constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT shift_planned_duration_check CHECK (planned_duration >= 0)
```

Solved the problem of removing this constraint before change column:

```
ALTER TABLE shift DROP CONSTRAINT shift_planned_duration_check;
```